# Add validator to formGroup without remove previous added validators

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Is there any way to add and just add a Validator to a form group without removing any validators that may have been added previously.

Lets say I have a large FormGroup and at a certain point I need to add a custom validator. `setValidators` removes any validators that may have been added to it. `formGroup.serValidators([customValidation, fromGroup.validator])` makes the `group` within the custom validation `null`. Any ideas?

Heres what I've got so far:

```js
const customValidation(thing, otherThing): ValidatorFn {
 // The group is null if I do formGroup.serValidators([customValidation, fromGroup.validator])
 return (group: FormGroup): ValidatorErros | null => {
 ... validate stuff
}

methodThatAddCustomValidator(formGroup) {
  formGroup.serValidators([customValidation, fromGroup.validator]);
  formGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

Edit: I've gotten some good questions and suggestions. Just trying to make it work with my architecture. I wonder is there any way I can just:

```js
formGroup.validator ?
  formGroup.validator.push(customValidation) :
  formGroup.setValidators(customValidation);

  formGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
```

^ This is the answer

Comment: maybe `formGroup.setValidators([customValidation, ...formGroup.validators])` ?

Comment: `validator` is possibly null. And that is not iterable.

Comment: For me, has no sense change the validators. Why not make yor custom validator take account the possible condition?

Comment: The custom validator is a niche validation. I'd rather not have it firing on all instances of formGroup.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to store your validators array in a separated variable, populate it at will at runtime and execute setValidators passing that variable afterwards. Use updateValueAndValidity as well for the new validators set to be taken into account.

```
formGroup: FormGroup;
validators: ValidatorFn[] = [Validators.required];

constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.formGroup = fb.group({
    field: ['', validators];
  });
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.addValidator(Validators.minLength(2));
  this.updateFieldValidation(this.formGroup.controls.field);
}

addValidator(validator: ValidatorFn) {
    this.validators.push(validator);
}

updateFieldValidation(control: AbstractControl) {
  control.setValidators(this.validators);
  control.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but our architecture is unable to do this.

That formGroup is spread between micro services and apps. Not in a single component or even module

Comment: Is the formGroup like a singleton or is it duplicated ?

Comment: It's a singleton. I guess my appreciation is where to store the validators that could be added that is accessible. Is there any way to just `formGroup.validators.push(customvValidator)` with a null check?

Comment: Yes, you could use your singleton class as a service, and make the addValidator function public. The function should then trigger the value and validity update as well for the formGroup to be updated. The current validators should still be stored in that service though. I can write the code if that's not clear